# Can trojans copy cookies of my website?

Tags: cookies

My website saves username and MD5ed password of user in cookies for login purpose.
My question is, can trojans in users pc steal that cookie and use it in another pc? If can, what is safe solution for remembering users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trojan can access any file stored on the infected PC, inluding cookies. What you can do to mitigate the risk is to store a unique ticket id instead of the hashed password in the cookie, and save some additional information on the server for that ticket on the server - browser version, operating system etc. and only accept the ticket if the metadata match, too. That said, it's still not perfectly safe that way; if your web service is really critical, you better ask for the password every single time. (But since a trojan probably also installs a keylogger, this still isn't enough to be really safe...)

Answer (score 3):

Of course they can.

You can mix user's IP into MD5, but it still doesn't protect user for 100% (since trojan can use user's IP as well as steal cookies).

As long as trojan uses *the same computer* there is no difference between user and trojan, hence protection is not theoretically possible.

Comment: Mixing with IP is a good idea. But dynamic IPs will change before expire time of cookie. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Trojans can also record the keys pressed by the user on the keyboard, so it's not really something you should worry about, because you can't do anything about it. It's the user responsibility to protect against malware.

What you should worry about are [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), the fact that [MD5 is not secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) and the fact that you should add [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to your hashes.

By the way, most websites use cookies not to store usernames and passwords, but ephemeral session IDs. These session IDs become invalid when the user clicks on the "log out" button.